# How to implement navigation between scene in corona like swipe view in android?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have three `Composer Scene` and I like to navigate between them by swiping left or right. What I have tried to do in my listener is to check

```
if( event.phase == "moved" ) then
    local dx = (event.x - event.xStart)
      if(dx > 20) then
        composer.removeScene("level", false)
        composer.gotoScene("wlc", {effect = "slideRight",time = 5000} )
      end
end
```

but in this case when I swipe the scene will be replaced and I can't stop it or go back
and what I need is to control sliding by my finger like `ViewPger` in android 
any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With Composer, once you start the scene transition, there is no way to abort.